# Passing a different callable to uWSGI instead of flask app object

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I am implementing uWSGI for my flask app for the first time.

There is a lot of configuration required before starting the flask app.  Instead of passing the uWSGI the app object, where I believe it calls app.run, is it possible to pass a separate callable, a method that sets up the configuration then calls app.run() itsself?

for example.  Every thing I see sets up the entry point like:

```
from ... import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
   ...
```

I am wondering if I could do something like

```
from ... import app

def setup():
   app.run(...)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   ...
```

and tell uWSGI to run `setup` instead of app.

Thank you!

Comment: Out of curiosity, when you measure the time it takes to do configuration, how long is it?

Comment: Well, its not that the configuration takes a long time.  But I inherited this code, and the previous developer imports the app, sets some configuration on the object manually from within a class then calls app.run.  so I am unsure how to change the code so that uWSGI can instantiate the class itself and then also call run on it.  So if I can proxy the callable, when that gets called, I can instantiate the class and not touch the other code.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, uwsgi is going to want to call **something**.run(). You can change **what** that something is by setting configuration `module` value. For example

```
--module myapp:foobar
```

so uwsgi calls `foobar.run()`. Not sure that's a big win, though. A common approach is to use whatever subclass you like and then, at the end may the assignment:

```
app = foobar
```

So uwsgi happily calls `app.run()`

Comment: Thats another thing I wasnt sure about.  I cant find anywhere in the documentation that uWSGI is looking for a method on the callable of run.  I just see we have to tell wsgi about a callable.